# Heat flow equation via Fourier Series

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, heat-equation

I know how to solve heat equations and wave equations defined on $\mathbb{R}^n\times(0,\infty)$ using Fourier transform. But I am having trouble solving similar equations defined on finite intervals using Fourier series. To be precise, how do I start on the equation
$$u_x = u_{tt}$$ with initial condition $$u(x,0) = f(x),$$ and $u$ is defined on $(a, b)\times(0, \infty)$?

The boundary conditions are $u(a,t) = u(b ,t) = 0$ for every $t>0$.

Comment: What are the boundary conditions?

Comment: I just added them.

Comment: The functions $X_n(x)=\sin\left(\frac{x-a}{b-a}n\pi\right)$ for $n=1,2,3,\cdots$ form an orthogonal basis of $L^2[a,b]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something contradictory in the wording of the question. The written equation is :
$$u_x=u_{tt}$$ 
which, in fact, is not the heat equation :
$$u_t=u_{xx}$$
as raised in the title and claimed the wording.

Supposing that this is a pypo, the next answer is the solving of the heat equation $u_t=u_{xx}$ with the specified boundary conditions ( and via Fourier series as requested ).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your endpoint condition is not sufficient. You'll need two conditions. For example,
$$
                  -f''=\lambda f \\
                   f(a)=f(b) \\
                   f'(a)=f'(b).
$$
is a well-posed eigenfunction problem with eigenfunctions $\{ \exp(2\pi n\frac{x-a}{b-a})\}_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}$, and eigenvalues $\lambda=\left(\frac{2\pi n}{b-a}\right)^2$

And the following problem is also a well-posed eigenfunction problem:
$$
                    -f''-\lambda f \\
                     f(a)=f(b) \\
                     f'(a)=-f'(b).
$$
Solutions include $\{\sin((2n+1)\pi\frac{x-a}{b-a})\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$

These are the most common types of periodic conditions, but there are others.